# Rendering to framebuffer and then to screen has reduced quality

Tags: opengl, framebuffer

I seem to have a problem with my rendering. When I render to a framebuffer and then to screen, the images just seem less vibrant and kind of faded. Even simple ones.

[image]

In the picture above, the pink box on the right is rendered directly onto the screen buffer and the ones on the left are first rendered onto a framebuffer and then onto the screen.

I am using a multisampled framebuffer and it seems to have made no difference. I tried only blending once by using GL_RGB on the framebuffer color texture that also didn't help. Any ideas?

Comment: You mean the text?

Comment: everything on the left of the single pink box on the right looks a bit blurred. including the text yes.

Comment: The coordinates matter. If the edge of the polygon falls "part way" through a pixel, then it's correct to draw it with an intermediate colour. That's part of what multisampling does - it gives you a way of rendering "microgeometry" (details of geometry that involve distances smaller than a pixel, addressing issues of aliasing.) On the other hand, maybe your transfer of the framebuffer to the screen should be using a GL_CLOSEST sampling technique (if you are expecting 1:1 frame buffer pixels to screen pixels) Or get your coordinates right. :)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The issue ended up being the size of the framebuffer. It was too small which made the quality suffer. I multiplied the width and height by 6 and the quality goes up.